# Calling notifications in other classes

Tags: android

I want to display notification, when condition completed in my Data Adapter, how can I do this? Notification I have build work fine when I initialize in Main Activity or call them with `(MainActivity)getActivity().method` in fragment but I want to call them from another class ?

Comment: can you explain clearly, what you want to do???

Comment: when the condition is completed in my data adapter, i want to call public void notification located in main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to pass the callback to the data adapter, and call it when event happens.

So you can use something like this:

```
public class DataAdapter {
    public interface OnMyEventListener{
        void onMyEvent();
    }

    private OnMyEventListener mOnMyEventListener;

    public void setOnMyEventListener(OnMyEventListener onMyEventListener) {
        mOnMyEventListener = onMyEventListener;
    }

    private void fireOnMyEvent(){
        if (mOnMyEventListener != null){
            mOnMyEventListener.onMyEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

To use it you should make your activity to implement interface of OnMyEventListener and add method onMyEvent();

```
public void onMyEvent(){
    showNotification();
}
```

And after creating of the adapter you can set your activity to listen it by calling setOnMyEventListener method.
Every time you detect the event you can call fireOnMyEvent method in the adapter.

And you can set listener in the next way:

```
DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter();
adapter.setOnMyEventListener(this).
```

**Update:**
If you mean by notification "system notification" http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html you can do this by passing context to your adapter and doing the same what you do in the activity, except: you can't call directly the

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

you should use context object that you pass, so you can call:

```
(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: understand all of it and i think I might work, but don't know where to put setOnMyEventListener

Comment: you can do it after you have created instance of adapter:

Comment: yes I mean system notification, so you say there is another method I can call it directly? without doing all the code above?